# Django signals sending twice

Tags: django, signals, activity-streams

I'm working on a simple Django reputation app, based on Actstream justquick/django-activity-stream/ that creates a signal to be used as:
    `rep.send(request.user, action='increase', target=obj, val=10)`

However, even with dispatch UID:

```
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from . signals import rep
from . receivers import rep_handler

class DjangoReputationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'django_rep'

    def ready(self):
        rep.connect(rep_handler, dispatch_uid='django_rep.models')`
```

Which I copied from [Actstream/apps.py](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/actstream/apps.py), I cannot get my signals to send only once. I've tried other unique strings and nothing seems to make a difference.

In my __ init__.py have:
`default_app_config = 'django_rep.apps.DjangoReputationConfig'`

Thanks! The repo is [here](https://github.com/andrewblaney/django_rep) if you want to see the code!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I tried many things, but in the end I had to resort to using an environment variable, like this:

```
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "xyz"

    def ready(self):
        if not os.environ.get("ready_called"): 
            # The development server instantiates MyConfig twice; running via gunicorn only once.
            os.environ["ready_called"] = "1" # Use this environment semaphore to prevent starting backgroundtaks more than once.
            import backgroundtasks
            backgroundtasks.install()
```

Comment: Thanks - It turns out is because I had the @receiver decorator on the receiver function and also connecting to it in AppConfig - was this your issue??

Comment: Nope, the only thing I do in my AppConfig is starting a background thread for some periodical database tasks. I _do_ use @receiver here and there as a decorator (I'm using allauth), but I don't connect explicitely to it.

Comment: For others who find themselves here: this happens in the development server because Django boots-up two processes, one is for the actual development server, and the other is to keep track of files change. Both active the `ready` signal.